# In-memory H2 database, insert not working in SpringBootTest

Tags: testing, spring-boot, h2

> I have a SpringBootApplicationWhich I wish to test.

Below are the details about my files

> application.properties

```
PRODUCT_DATABASE_PASSWORD=
PRODUCT_DATABASE_USERNAME=sa
PRODUCT_DATABASE_CONNECTION_URL=jdbc:h2:file:./target/db/testdb
PRODUCT_DATABASE_DRIVER=org.h2.Driver

RED_SHIFT_DATABASE_PASSWORD=
RED_SHIFT_DATABASE_USERNAME=sa
RED_SHIFT_DATABASE_CONNECTION_URL=jdbc:h2:file:./target/db/testdb
RED_SHIFT_DATABASE_DRIVER=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=h2
```

> ConfigurationClass

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ProductDataAccessConfig.class, RedShiftDataAccessConfig.class})
public class TestConfig {

}
```

> Main Test Class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestConfig.class,ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
    public class MainTest {


 @Autowired(required = true)
 @Qualifier("dataSourceRedShift")
 private DataSource dataSource;
 @Test
 public void testHourlyBlock() throws Exception {
    insertDataIntoDb(); //data sucessfully inserted
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, new String[]{}); //No data found

  }
}
```

> Data Access In Application.class;

```
 try (Connection conn = dataSourceRedShift.getConnection();
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() {
//access inserted data

}
```

Please Help!
PS for the spring boot application the test beans are being picked so bean instantiation definitely not a problem. I think I am missing some properties.

I do not use hibernate in my application and data goes off even within the same application context (child context). i.e. I run a spring boot application which reads that data inserted earlier

Comment: In the test, by default the changes will rollback, do you disable the transaction rollback?

Comment: I am not using any transaction manager. 
Is it configured by default? 
I did try connection.commit after each query didn't help!

Comment: You can refer to thie [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-tx-enabling-transactions)

Comment: I do not use hibernate in my application and data goes off even within the same application context (child context). i.e. I run a spring boot application which reads that data inserted earlier. Should I still implement transaction manager?

Comment: So you need add all those info in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.
removing spring.datasource.platform=h2 from the application.properties.
Made my h2 data persists.
But I still wish to know how is h2 starting automatically?

Comment: probably because of autoconfigurations h2 is enabled. By adding a h2 dependency springboot will auto configure h2 db.

Comment: Thanks, I was having the same problem, and now it's working.